# How can I prevent '.startTyping()' waiting forever

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So basically I wanted my bot to **start typing** right before it executes a command, and **stop typing** if the command is fully executed. In order to achieve this, I tried this:

```js
// The first line just deletes the entered command from the user, so the chat looks cleaner
message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
        .then(() => message.channel.startTyping())
        .then(() => execute(message, args, Discord, client))
        .then(() => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
```

The problem is, that it gets stuck at `.then(() => message.channel.startTyping())`.

I looked a bit around in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=startTyping) an noticed, that `.startTyping()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so I tried it this way:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
        .then(() => message.channel.startTyping()
            .then(() => execute(message, args, Discord, client))
            .then(() => message.channel.stopTyping(true)));
```

But this doesn't work either. The description for [`.startTyping()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=startTyping) says

> Resolves once the bot stops typing gracefully, or rejects when an error occurs

If I got that right, the `Promise` only resolves, if the `.stopTyping()` method is called?

Can somebody explain this to me? I just need by bot to **start** typing **before**, and **stop** typing **after** executing the command

Comment: it should stop typing when your bot sends a message

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I was able to fix it by myself:

```js
message.delete()
    .then(() => {
        message.channel.startTyping();
        execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    })
    .then(() => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
```